# What does txpower exactly means?

Tags: network, wifi

I stumbled upon a guide which says increase txpower by setting region to some place. So my doubt is
1.What does txpower means?
2.What if if increased txpower will there be any trouble?
I am saying txpower of my wireless adapter.

Comment: Transmission power Tx means transmission. Rx mean receiver. I presume. But that is OT for infosec. What is the context? You should update your question to provide context and and relevant to info sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tx is the transmission power.

Some countries has different law regarding this, like Japan for example on which you can use channels from 1 to 14.

If you use channel that is not allowed in your country or if you put a custom firmware on your device and you transmit with more power than allowed in your country you could be in trouble. Of course this is hard to detect if you use it for home use. Anyway I think is a good practice to do the opposite, recuding Tx to avoid the problem of your wireless network going too much outside of your home.

Here is a list with the [powers/channels allowed per country](https://w.wol.ph/2015/08/28/maximum-wifi-transmission-power-country/)

Answer (score 0):

TXpower(transmission power) is the strength of the router's signal. If you are looking to reach a wider range, you configure the txpower to a higher setting in the router's settings.

One of the main concerns is security; a wider signal range is heard by more neighbors. If any of them is malicious and your router lacks proper encryption, you would be susceptible to malicious attacks. Hence why people suggest to leave the txpower at the default setting where it is only available to you; unless of course you have a viable reason to change it.